# Problem with soft body collision animation

Tags: collision

I'm new to Blender.

How to make animation so that objects deform and interact with each other?

I make a thread - collision, animate it and make a body - soft body, but it turns out not at all.

The thread falls into the body. I did not find anything in the tutorials please tell me what is available.

[Blend File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2ad151w9yu4nyceydhxiz/file.zip?rlkey=d0bs5z0tkijmu0ow7e218nb5c&dl=0)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: fine. Sorry. Will know
I thought that simply my question would not be solved and I added the file

Comment: you mesh has a ridiculous high amount of vertices. Maybe you wanna watch some beginner softbody tutorials? There are lots of them in youtube. Anyway...if i gave your one mesh a "good" amount of vertices like so: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/krZzI.png then i got this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7JFS.gif Basic rule is: your softbody animation will look totally different if you have more or less vertices. So you have to have (as always with Blender) a bit of experience to know how it looks good

Comment: Not to nitpick, but in your blend file there is a *Cloth* simulation and not a *Soft Body* simulation. Just saying that because there are two different simulation types in Blender with those names. -- Also, you have the entire edge of the towel pinned. I'm not sure that's a good idea, because pinned vertices are not affected by the simulation, and they don't move. They are just pinned. You can turn off gravity to prevent the mesh from falling.

Answer (score 0):

*Cloth* simulation seems to work better than *Soft Body* for what you're trying to do. Here I've give a *Collision* to the circle and created a shapekey animation so that it squeezes the cylinder. As for the cylinder it has a *Cloth* simulation, a bit of *Pressure* and its Field *Weights > Gravity* is turned off:

[image]

Settings:

[image]

The mesh, I've given a *Subidivision Surface* modifier with a level of 2:

[image]

File here: [image]

Comment: yes, but it doesn't quite create the effect that I threw away as a reference, and cloth is hardly used in the reference

Comment: Does it need to be Soft Body and is it animated or is it a single image?

Comment: it's animation. this is what i need to do. But I can't find a solution to this for almost a week :( https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/k0u67fjchbyp5onkpa3o3/IMG_4437.MP4?rlkey=dr536jd0t2hciovesiyiy9xw7&dl=0

Comment: I've edited, still a Cloth simulation, I think it's pretty close to what you show @Vlad

Comment: thank you, I will try with these settings and let you know the result. And how much did you put subdivision on the objects?

Comment: See my edit (Subdivision Surface with a level of 2)

Comment: I repeated your settings in detail and I got ... you can take a look -__-
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/q6ukswxn8siksu7zdnyhu/1.blend?rlkey=ewzc3aunaj530a5ngbeoghb2s&dl=0

Comment: You need to flip the faces of your rings or disable the Collision > Single Sided option of the object, see my edit, I've shared my file

Comment: wow, just one checkbox was crucial. Thank you so much. Maybe you know where you can learn this in detail? tutorials?

Comment: I don't know if there's a tuto in particular that would help, maybe check this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLuHr1unnyg but i may make one about your question